# $\int \sqrt{1+2 \cos ^2 \theta} \; d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm solving a physics problem where I'm trying to find the equation of motion of this setup.

[image]

I've arrived on the equation $$\frac{u}{l}dt=\sqrt{1+2 \cos ^2 \theta} \; d\theta$$

I tried and failed to solve the resulting integral:
$$\int_{\pi}^{\alpha}\sqrt{1+2 \cos ^2 \theta} \; d\theta$$

Can anyone help me

Comment: This is an elliptic integral. No chance to find a closed form.

Comment: Use WolframAlpha unless you have been taught how to deal with elliptical integrals. Also check your work to see how you arrived on an equation that you have not been taught how to deal with. May be there is an error or may be you can do it differently.

Comment: Usually, in elementary physics, these are handled with small angle approximations, generally to first order. I'm not sure why you chose that particular angle to deal with, but if you consider the complementary angle (call it $\alpha$), then you have the restoring force $F=2T\sin\alpha$, and when you make the small displacement/small angle approximation, you get $F=ma=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\approx 2T\alpha$. By similarly making another small angle approximation for the displacement (the second time derivative of which is the acceleration), you should be able to get the classical SHM equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admitting that your equation is correct, you will face
$$\frac u l t=\sqrt{3} E\left(\alpha \left|\frac{2}{3}\right.\right)-2 \sqrt{3}   E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$ where appears  the elliptic integral of the second kind and  the complte elliptic integral.

I suppose that you are looking for $\alpha(t)$ which is not possible.

However, we can make quite accurate approximations. For simplicity, I shall let $k=\frac u l t$.

For example, built around $\alpha=\pi$, the Taylor series of the rhs is
$$\sqrt{3} (\alpha -\pi )-\frac{(\alpha -\pi )^3}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{(\alpha -\pi
   )^5}{30 \sqrt{3}}+O\left((\alpha -\pi    )^7\right)$$ which is more than decent for $\pi \leq \alpha\leq \frac 32 \pi$.

Using series reversion,
$$\alpha=\pi +\frac{k}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{k^3}{27 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{7 k^5}{2430
   \sqrt{3}}+O\left(k^7\right)$$

Doing the same around $\alpha=2\pi$, the rhs would be
$$2 \sqrt{3} E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\sqrt{3} (\alpha -2 \pi )-\frac{(\alpha -2 \pi
   )^3}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{(\alpha -2 \pi )^5}{30 \sqrt{3}}+O\left((\alpha -2 \pi )^7\right)$$ which is more than decent for $\frac 32 \pi \leq \alpha\leq 2 \pi$.

Using series reversion,
$$\alpha=2 \pi +c+\frac{c^3}{9}+\frac{7 c^5}{270}+O\left(c^7\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad c=\frac{k}{\sqrt{3}}-2 E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Numerically, $ E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \approx 1.26119$.